# Formatting External USB Hard drive problem

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd, format, fat32

I'm new the the linux community. I recently upgraded my old laptop with a ssd and installed Ubuntu 16.10. I plan on using the old hard drive as a external hard drive for videos and music. I was starting to format the drive and my battery died while the hard drive was formatting. Now when I plug in my drive, it doesn't show up and I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Plug it in, then run `dmesg | tail` in a terminal window, and post the output.

Comment: dmesg | tail [  139.384892] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[  139.386008] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  139.386015] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 3b 00 00 00
[  139.387137] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  139.387146] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  139.388457] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  139.475052]  sdb: sdb1 < sdb5 sdb6 sdb7 >
[  139.479127] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

Comment: [  140.429215] EXT4-fs (sdb5): recovery complete
[  140.429225] EXT4-fs (sdb5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

Comment: It's not a good idea to dump such outputs into comments. Either edit the question, or use pastebin.com.